# SQL Redshift difference in days between 2 timestamps

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

In my Redshift table I have 2 columns that stores timestamp values: **start_date_time and end_date_time**.

I need to find the difference between **start_date_time and end_date_time**, such that, if difference is 1 day, then result should be 1. If diff is 12 hours, than result should be 0.5, if diff is 8 hours - than 0.3333 etc.

How can I do this? I tried to use datediff function: but that will not return what I wanted:

```
select datediff(day,'2011-12-31 8:30:00','2011-12-31 20:30:00') as day_diff;
```

Will result in 0. But I need 0.5, because difference is 12 hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then just do it in hours and divide by 24.0?

```
DATEDIFF(HOUR,'2011-12-31 8:30:00','2011-12-31 20:30:00') / 24.0
```

Or for better granularity, in minutes or seconds?

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2011-12-31 8:30:00','2011-12-31 20:30:00') / 1440.0

DATEDIFF(SECOND,'2011-12-31 8:30:00','2011-12-31 20:30:00') / 86400.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm trying to diff between 2 timestamps as follows: select datediff(month, TIMESTAMP 'Jan 17,2021  00:00:00', TIMESTAMP 'Feb 1,2021  00:00:00'). I'd like it to return 0, but instead get 1. Any ideas of how doing such diff for months/years? Thanks In advance

Comment: @NI6 Please don't use comments to ask questions, please open a new question, tagging people if appropriate. Also, please check if your question has been asked before; for example, Google gave me this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021316/calculate-exact-month-difference-between-two-dates-in-redshift

Answer (score 3):

Use a smaller time unit:

```
select datediff(hour, '2011-12-31 8:30:00', '2011-12-31 20:30:00')/24.0 as day_diff;
```

Or:

```
select datediff(minute, '2011-12-31 8:30:00', '2011-12-31 20:30:00')/(24.0 * 60) as day_diff;
```

Or:

```
select datediff(second, '2011-12-31 8:30:00', '2011-12-31 20:30:00')/(24.0 * 60 * 60) as day_diff;
```