# Calculate exact month-difference between two dates in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c715a3f2ef4da8cce7baebdad44febae)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    inventory_date DATE,
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    product_value VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(inventory_date, product_name, product_value)
VALUES 
('2020-10-19', 'Product_A', '400'),
('2020-10-22', 'Product_B', '400'),
('2020-11-20', 'Product_C', '900'),
('2020-11-25', 'Product_D', '300');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    product_name    |     months_in_inventory    |
--------------------|----------------------------|----------
    Product_A       |            2               | 
    Product_B       |            1               | 
    Product_C       |            1               | 
    Product_D       |            0               |
```

---

I want to calculate the `months_in_inventory` by calculating the difference between a `fixed_date` and the `inventory_date`. 
In the example the `fixed_date` is  `'2020-12-20'` and I am using it my query. 
In `postgresSQL` I was able to achieve the expected result with query from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020993/calculate-exact-month-difference-between-two-dates):

```
SELECT 
iv.product_name,

(EXTRACT(year FROM age('2020-12-20'::date, MAX(iv.inventory_date::date))) * 12 +
EXTRACT(month FROM age('2020-12-20'::date, MAX(iv.inventory_date::date)))
) AS months_in_inventory

FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, when I run this query on `redshift` I get error:

```
ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

How do I need to change the query to make it work on `redshift`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support `age()`.  Use `months_between()`:

```
SELECT iv.product_name,
       FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN('2020-12-20'::date, iv.inventory_date::date)) as months_in_inventory
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: What is the FLOOR function doing?

Comment: @Michi . . . The return type is `float`.  You want an integer:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MONTHS_BETWEEN_function.html.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's answer is dead on.  I just want to add a note for future readers of this post:

When you see "ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables." translate it to "ERROR: You used a leader-node only function with compute-node data. Use a different function."

This question comes up constantly here and in my consulting.  I wish AWS would provide a more helpful error message and identify the leader-node only function in question.  This has been the error message forever and the confusion around it continues.